# Getting an interface from a contract deployed on etherscan?

Tags: etherscan, interfaces

Given a contract address, is their some way to get an interface of the code deployed there?
For example, I want to create an interface containing all the methods I can use on the balancer vault here:
https://etherscan.io/address/0xba12222222228d8ba445958a75a0704d566bf2c8#code

I know I can get the abi at the bottom, but is there some easy way to generate the interface IVault.sol, specifically?

I realize that in this case, I can simply use the IVault.sol file that's included. If it were not included, is their some tool online I can quickly use to generate the file?